# json contains string proper format

Tags: json

I want to identify the text which contains the exact string within it. For example I'm looking for the word "good" using `contains("good")` function.

Here are examples:

```
A= "If you don’t have good intentions", 
B= " the music is great #goodvibes"
C= "feeling cozy and relaxed"
```

when trying to check the text using `contains("good")` function.

it give me A and B however, I want the answer to be A only.

Can someone guide me if I'm using the correct function and format.

Thank you.

Comment: you can split by whitespace and then check

Comment: added as answer, you can mark as accepted one

Answer (score 0):

i think its better to use regex, use boundary in regex like the below:

```
\bgood\b
```

take a look at below example

https://regexr.com/4suss

Answer (score 0):

as you want to check that string for a complete word within a sentence, split that with `whitespace` and compare that string[] against that string. I know this is not optimal solution but will work.